# Sitecore Rich Text Editor - Adding a button

Tags: javascript, sitecore

I followed this site's example of how to add a button in the Rich Text Editor in Sitecore http://www.tanasuk.com/blog/Sitecore%20Rich%20Text%20Editor and when I pull up my editor with the new button, I'm getting a 'The commmand "Insert Help" is not implemented yet.' What could I be missing to make sure it has been implemented? I even took out commands in the RichText Commands.js to see if the buttons were connected, and they weren't. Meaning, the other buttons in the RichText Editor still worked, even though I took out the RadEditorCommandList profile of that button. Is there another place where these commands are stored or do I need to alter another file to make the command work?

I'm working in Sitecore 8

Comment: Open your browser Developer Tools and check if correct(changed) “RichTextCommands.js” was loaded. If no, find out why wrong js file was loaded, try to clear browser cache.

Comment: yeah its loaded, so no idea why it isn't working

Comment: And does loaded “RichTextCommands.js” contain definition for "Insert Help" ?

Comment: yes it does.......

Comment: it just started working all of a sudden... no clue what I did

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following link http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.be/2012/10/add-custom-button-in-rich-text-editor.html.

It make use of an implementation that will create a button without overriding the code for sitecore and RADEditor

Moreover, you can check the the part two which add a richtext webedit button with a custom dialog: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2013/01/add-richtext-webedit-button-with-custom.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the browser cache for me. I cleared my cache and the issue resolved.